# WCF service stops responding due to "The semaphore timeout period has expired"

Tags: wcf

I have a self-hosted WCF service stops responding after few days of work.

In the client-side I get this error -

```
The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.8719872. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

I've enabled tracing at the server-side, and this is what I get in the error -

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-02-01T04:30:12.1624528Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{1fbbf506-77e3-46cf-8a5d-e9ddba1ce43a}" />
<Execution ProcessName="****************" ProcessID="4232" ThreadID="27" />
<Channel />
<Computer>ESAPI</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>**********.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The semaphore timeout period has expired</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.SecurityRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage9(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.Start()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveRequestAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult.ReceiveMessage(Object state)
at System.Runtime.ActionItem.DefaultActionItem.Invoke()
at System.Runtime.ActionItem.CallbackHelper.InvokeWithoutContext(Object state)
at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The semaphore timeout period has expired ---&gt; System.Net.HttpListenerException: The semaphore timeout period has expired
   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BytesReadPositionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.HttpListenerException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The semaphore timeout period has expired</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BytesReadPositionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): The semaphore timeout period has expired
   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BytesReadPositionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>79</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

**Any ideas how can I solve this?**

**What else can I do to get more details about it?**

Comment: Could you post an extract of the service code? Seems like a service doesn't return a response to a client in the defined time.

Comment: @oleksii - The code is pretty big, it will be a problem to post the code. Why there's no TimeOutException or some meaningful exception instead of this one?

Comment: it seems like you do have a TimeOutEx: "The request channel timed out ...". Is there any code that takes more than one min to process the request? If so then you can increase the specified in the error message waiting values. If the call is quick, then there is a resource leak of some sort and the service failed to return the response within 1 min (check the service load and logs). Alternatively, you can make you clients to poll for the status of long running operation, which is a quick call and it keeps only essential communication.

Comment: The timeOutException is in the client. The operation is very quick, shouldn't take a minute.

Comment: Is it under high load? Do you have throttling configured? Does the service use user-defined locking?

Comment: High load is relative, it gets a request about every second. I configured the throttling to 100 (all parameters). Have some locking, but I believe I don't have deadlocks or locks for long time.

Comment: I have *exactly* the same issue with my self-hosted WCF service. Even the load is the same as in you case. Still can't find the reason why this happens, and it happens about once a month.